# How to strip out all of the links of an HTML file in Bash or grep or batch and store them in a text file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep, cut

I have a file that is [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML), and it has about 150 anchor tags. I need only the links from these tags, AKA, `<a href="*http://www.google.com*"></a>`. I want to get only the http://www.google.com part.

When I run a grep,

```
cat website.htm | grep -E '<a href=".*">' > links.txt
```

this returns the entire line to me that it found on not the link I want, so I tried using a [`cut`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) command:

```
cat drawspace.txt | grep -E '<a href=".*">' | cut -d’”’ --output-delimiter=$'\n' > links.txt
```

Except that it is wrong, and it doesn't work give me some error about wrong parameters... So I assume that the file was supposed to be passed along too. Maybe like `cut -d’”’ --output-delimiter=$'\n' grepedText.txt > links.txt`.

But I wanted to do this in one command if possible... So I tried doing an [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) command.

```
cat drawspace.txt | grep '<a href=".*">' | awk '{print $2}’
```

But this wouldn't run either. It was asking me for more input, because I wasn't finished....

I tried writing a batch file, and it told me FINDSTR is not an internal or external command... So I assume my environment variables were messed up and rather than fix that I tried installing grep on Windows, but that gave me the same error....

The question is, what is the right way to strip out the HTTP links from [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML)? With that I will make it work for my situation.

P.S. I've read so many links/Stack Overflow posts that showing my references would take too long.... If example HTML is needed to show the complexity of the process then I will add it.

I also have a Mac and PC which I switched back and forth between them to use their shell/batch/grep command/terminal commands, so either or will help me.

I also want to point out I'm in the correct directory

[image]

HTML:

```
<tr valign="top">
    <td class="beginner">
      B03&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b03/simple-symmetry">Simple Symmetry</a>  </td>
</tr>

<tr valign="top">
  <td class="beginner">
    B04&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </td>
  <td>
      <a href="http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b04/faces-and-a-vase">Faces and a Vase</a> </td>
</tr>

<tr valign="top">
    <td class="beginner">
      B05&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b05/blind-contour-drawing">Blind Contour Drawing</a> </td>
</tr>

<tr valign="top">
    <td class="beginner">
        B06&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b06/seeing-values">Seeing Values</a> </td>
</tr>
```

Expected output:

```
http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b03/simple-symmetry
http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b04/faces-and-a-vase
http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b05/blind-contour-drawing
etc.
```

Comment: bleh it didn't put the links on separate lines......basically links connected by a \n character

Comment: As usual, [don't use regex to parse HTML](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1224532/get-links-from-an-html-page

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
$ sed -n 's/.*href="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' file
http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b03/simple-symmetry
http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b04/faces-and-a-vase
http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b05/blind-contour-drawing
http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b06/seeing-values
```

Comment: this worked for me, unfortunately my html is more complex so i don't get exactly what i want, but that is through the fault of the question XD thank you, this simplifies it so manual work is not a burden

Comment: sed is a Stream EDitor. Use it for simple substitutions on a single line. It has a ton of language constructs but the only useful ones are s, g, and p (with -n) - all of the rest became obsolete once awk was invented in the mid-1970s (but for some reason people keep dragging them out and using them).

Comment: so awk replaced sed ?

Comment: No, sed is still the best tool for simple substitutions on a single line, it's just that sed was invented before awk so it had a lot of language constructs to let you do very complex things but once awk was invented it had a MUCH improved language for handling complex operations so you no longer needed sed FOR THAT but those sed language constructs were never removed so they still exist today and people use them inexplicably today to create the most monstrously unreadable scripts.

Comment: Here's the rules: use `grep` to find patterns and print the matching lines, use `sed` for simple substitutions on a single line, and use `awk` for any other text manipulation. `grep` and `sed` were both created to simplify and are named based on common uses of the old text editor `ed` - `grep` is named after `g/re/p` which are the `ed` commands to find a regexp and print the matching line while `sed` is `Stream ED`.

Comment: thank you for the information :3 that will help me understand the points when i get around to reading up on it

Comment: You're welcome. There are books out there about sed and awk but you do NOT need a book to learn what sed (or grep) is good at so just get the book "Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition" by Arnold Robbins if you feel an urge to buy a book about parsing text using UNIX tools.

Comment: thanks man!
yours was the first of dozen google results that worked on a mac terminal!

Comment: This didn't do it for me.  Only 3 links out of 15

Comment: @DenisZ not much anyone can do to help you with whatever your problem is given just that "it's not working" comment. If this doesn't do what you want then your input doesn't look like the input in this question and so you shouldn't be trying to use this solution to a different problem than the one you have. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 33):

You can use `grep` for this:

```
grep -Po '(?<=href=")[^"]*' file
```

It prints everything after `href="` until a new double quote appears.

With your given input it returns:

```
http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b03/simple-symmetry
http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b04/faces-and-a-vase
http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b05/blind-contour-drawing
http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b06/seeing-values
```

*Note that it is not necessary to write `cat drawspace.txt | grep '<a href=".*">'`, you can get rid of the [useless use of cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) with `grep '<a href=".*">' drawspace.txt`.*

#### Another example

```
$ cat a
hello <a href="httafasdf">asdas</a>
hello <a href="hello">asdas</a>
other things

$ grep -Po '(?<=href=")[^"]*' a
httafasdf
hello
```

Comment: cat website.htm | grep -Po '(?<=href=")[^"]*' > links.txt
is not working telling me i am using grep wrong and showing me how to use it

Comment: oh you mentioned that, my you are fast

Comment: i ma reading a file and putting the output into a new file so that would be like grep -Po '(?<=href=")[^"]*' website.htm > links.txt

Comment: Exactly, @A'saDickens, just redirect as you indicate.

Comment: Which `grep` are you using? Are you in a *nix environment? Just in case, escape `"` ----> `grep -Po '(?<=href=\")[^\"]*'`

Comment: @A'saDickens The grep options used here require GNU grep which may not be present on your UNIX installation.

Comment: i'm on my mac, i uploaded a picture, maybe that will help

Comment: Just a note to save users of Mac terminals the trouble: the `-Po` in the above code sets the `grep` up for Perl-style syntax (`-P`) and printing only the matched lines (`-o`, cf. [docs)](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html). The `-P` argument might not work on your Mac, the `-o` should, but neither is not essential for this to work.

Answer (score 6):

My guess is your PC or Mac will not have the lynx command installed by default (it's available for free on the web), but lynx will let you do things like this:

$lynx -dump -image_links -listonly /usr/share/xdiagnose/workloads/youtube-reload.html

Output:
References

1. file://localhost/usr/share/xdiagnose/workloads/youtube-reload.html
2. http://www.youtube.com/v/zeNXuC3N5TQ&hl=en&fs=1&autoplay=1

It is then a simple matter to grep for the http: lines. And there even may be lynx options to print just the http: lines (lynx has many, many options).

Answer (score 2):

Use `grep` to extract all the lines with links in them and then use `sed` to pull out the URLs:

```
grep -o '<a href=".*">' *.html | sed 's/\(<a href="\|\">\)//g' > link.txt;
```

Comment: `sed: 1: "s/\(<a href="\|\">)//g": RE error: parentheses not balanced`

Answer (score 2):

As per comment of [triplee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264626/how-to-strip-out-all-of-the-links-of-an-html-file-in-bash-or-grep-or-batch-and-s#comment32038814_21264626), using regex to parse HTML or XML files is essentially not done. Tools such as `sed` and `awk` are extremely powerful for handling text files, but when it boils down to parsing complex-structured data — such as XML, HTML, JSON, ... —  they are nothing more than a sledgehammer. Yes, you can get the job done, but sometimes at a tremendous cost.  For handling such delicate files, you need a bit more finesse by using a more targetted set of tools.

In case of parsing XML or HTML, one can easily use [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php).

In case of an XHTML file, you can use :

```
xmlstarlet sel --html  -N "x=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" \
               -t -m '//x:a/@href' -v . -n
```

where `-N` gives the XHTML namespace if any, this is recognized by

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

However, As HTML pages are often not well-formed XML, it might be handy to clean it up a bit using [`tidy`](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/). In the example case above this gives then :

```
$ tidy -q -numeric -asxhtml --show-warnings no <file.html> \
  | xmlstarlet sel --html -N "x=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" \
                   -t -m '//x:a/@href' -v . -n
http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b03/simple-symmetry
http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b04/faces-and-a-vase
http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b05/blind-contour-drawing
http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b06/seeing-values
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a (more general) `dash` script, which can compare the URLs in [ *a file* / [ *files in a folder* ] ] compared to URLs in [ *a file* / [ *files in a group of folders ± other files* ] ] - where URLs are delimited (recognized) by (must contain) `://` (call this script with the `--help` flag to find out how to use it - the script should work out of the box on Linux and Mac operating systems):

```
#!/bin/dash

PrintURLs () {
    #extract_urls_command="$insert_NL_before_URLs_command|$strip_NON_URL_text_command|$delete_lines_not_containing_an_URL"

    if [ "$domains_flag" = "1" ]; then
        extract_urls_command="$extract_urls_command|$get_domains_command"
    fi
    {
        eval path_to_search="\$$1"
        current_file_group="$2"
        
        GetMimeType path_to_search current_mime_type
        printf "\033]0;%s\007" "Loading text files from group [$current_file_group] - file $count...">"$print_to_screen"
        if [ "$current_mime_type" = "directory" ]; then
            cd "$path_to_search"
            if [ ! "$skip_non_text_files_flag" = "1" ]; then
                printf "\033]0;%s\007" "Loading non text files from group [$current_file_group]...">"$print_to_screen"
                cmd=" -exec unzip -q -c '{}' 'word/_rels/*'"; eval find . $find_negation -type d $find_negation -path '.' -a \\\( -name '*.docx' \\\) "$find_params" "$cmd" \\\;
                cmd=" -exec unzip -q -c '{}' 'xl/worksheets/_rels/*'"; eval find . $find_negation -type d $find_negation -path '.' -a \\\( -name '*.xlsx' \\\) "$find_params" "$cmd" \\\;
                cmd=" -exec unzip -q -c '{}' 'ppt/slides/rels/*'"; eval find . $find_negation -type d $find_negation -path '.' -a \\\( -name '*.pptx' -o -name '*.ppsx' \\\) "$find_params" "$cmd" \\\;
                cmd=" -exec unzip -q -c '{}' 'content.xml'"; eval find . $find_negation -type d $find_negation -path '.' -a \\\( -name '*.odt' -o -name '*.ods' -o -name '*.odp' \\\) "$find_params" "$cmd" \\\;
                cmd=" -exec pdftohtml '{}' '-'"; eval find . $find_negation -type d $find_negation -path '.' -a \\\( -name '*.pdf' \\\) "$find_params" "$cmd" \\\;
            fi
            eval find . $find_negation -type d $find_negation -path '.' "$find_params"|{
                count=0
                while IFS= read file; do
                    GetMimeType file current_mime_type
                    if [ ! "$current_mime_type" = "binary" ]; then
                        count=$(($count+1))
                        printf "\033]0;%s\007" "Loading text files from group [$current_file_group] - file $count...">"$print_to_screen"
                        cat "$file"
                    fi
                done
            }
        elif [ "$current_mime_type" = "ascii" ] || [ "$current_mime_type" = "utf" ]; then
            count=$(($count+1))
            cat "$path_to_search"
        fi
        printf "\033]0;%s\007" "Extracting URLs from group [$current_file_group]...">"$print_to_screen"
    } 2>/dev/null|eval "$extract_urls_command"
}

StoreURLsWithLineNumbers () {
    
    count_all="0"
    mask="00000000000000000000"
    
    #For <file group 1>: initialise next variables:
    file_group="1"
    count=0
    
    dff_command_text=""
    if [ ! "$dff_command_flag" = "0" ]; then
        dff_command_text="Step $dff_command_flag - "
    fi
    
    for line in $(PrintURLs file_params_1 1; printf '\n%s\n' "### Separator ###";    for i in $(GenerateSequence 2 $file_params_0); do PrintURLs file_params_$i 2; done;); do
        if [ "$line" = "### Separator ###" ]; then
            eval lines$file_group\1\_0=$count
            eval lines$file_group\2\_0=$count
            
            #For <file group 2>: initialise next variables:
            file_group="2";
            count="0"
            continue;
        fi
        
        printf "\033]0;%s\007" "Storing URLs into memory [$dff_command_text""group $file_group]: $(($count + 1))...">"$print_to_screen"
        count_all_prev=$count_all
        count_all=$(($count_all+1))
        count=$(($count+1))
        if [ "${#count_all_prev}" -lt "${#count_all}" ]; then
            mask="${mask%?}"
        fi
        number="$mask$count_all"
        
        eval lines$file_group\1\_$count=\"\$number\"
        eval lines$file_group\2\_$count=\"\$line\" #URL
    done;
    eval lines$file_group\1\_0=$count
    eval lines$file_group\2\_0=$count
}

GetOSType () {
    if [ -n "$1" ]; then
        case "$(uname -s)" in
        *"Darwin"* | *"BSD"* )
            eval $1="BSD-based"
            ;;
        *"Linux"* )
            eval $1="Linux"
            ;;
        * )
            eval $1="Other"
            ;;
        esac
    else
        echo 'ERROR: GetOSType: Expected 1 parameter!'>&2
        echo 'Press Enter to exit...'>"$print_to_screen"
        read temp
    fi
}

trap1 () {
    CleanUp
    #if not running in a subshell: print "Aborted"
    if [ "$dff_command_flag" = "0" ]; then
        printf "\n""Aborted.""\n">"$print_to_screen"
    fi
    
    #kill all children processes, suppressing "Terminated" message:
    kill -s PIPE -- -$$
    
    exit
}

CleanUp () {
    
    #Restore "INTERRUPT" (CTRL-C) and "TERMINAL STOP" (CTRL-Z) signals:
    trap - INT
    trap - TSTP
    
    #Clear the title:
    printf "\033]0;%s\007" "">"$print_to_screen"
    
    #Restore initial IFS:
    #IFS="$initial_IFS"
    unset IFS
    
    #Restore initial directory:
    cd "$initial_dir"
    
    DestroyArray flag_params
    DestroyArray file_params
    DestroyArray find_params
    DestroyArray lines11
    DestroyArray lines12
    DestroyArray lines21
    DestroyArray lines22
    
    ##Kill current shell with PID $$:
    #kill -INT $$

}

DestroyArray () {
    eval eval array_length=\'\$$1\_0\'
    if [ -z "$array_length" ]; then array_length=0; fi
    for i in $(GenerateSequence 1 $array_length); do
        eval unset $1\_$i
    done
    eval unset $1\_0
}

PrintErrorExtra () {
    {
    
        printf '%s\n' "Command path:"
        printf '%s\n' "$current_shell_full_path '$current_script_path'"
        
        printf "\n"
        
        #Flag parameters are printed non-quoted:
        printf '%s\n' "Flags:"
        for i in $(GenerateSequence 1 $flag_params_0); do
            eval current_param="\"\$flag_params_$i\""
            printf '%s\n' "$current_param"
        done
        if [ "$flag_params_0" = "0" ]; then printf '%s\n' "<none>"; fi
        printf "\n"
        
        #Path parameters are printed quoted with '':
        printf '%s\n' "Paths:"
        for i in $(GenerateSequence 1 $file_params_0); do
            eval current_param="\"\$file_params_$i\""
            printf '%s\n' "'$current_param'"
        done
        if [ "$file_params_0" = "0" ]; then printf '%s\n' "<none>"; fi
        printf "\n"

        #Find parameters are printed quoted with '':
        printf '%s\n' "'find' parameters:"
        for i in $(GenerateSequence 1 $find_params_0); do
            eval current_param="\"\$find_params_$i\""
            printf '%s\n' "'$current_param'"
        done
        if [ "$find_params_0" = "0" ]; then printf '%s\n' "<none>"; fi
        printf "\n"
    }>"$print_error_messages"
}

DisplayHelp () {
    printf '%s\n' ""
    printf '%s\n' " - UNIQue Links - a dash shell script to compare URLs ( containing '://' ) in a file/(files in a )folder compared to a group of files/(files in )folders"
    printf '%s\n' "     "
    printf '%s\n' "     Usage:"
    printf '%s\n' "         "
    printf '%s\n' "         dash '/path/to/this/script.sh' <flags> '/path/to/file1' ... '/path/to/fileN' [ --find-parameters <find_parameters> ]"
    printf '%s\n' "         where:"
    printf '%s\n' "         - The group 1: '/path/to/file1' and the group 2: '/path/to/file2' ... '/path/to/fileN' - are considered the two groups of files to be compared"
    printf '%s\n' "         "
    printf '%s\n' "         - <flags> can be:"
    printf '%s\n' "             --help"
    printf '%s\n' "                 - displays this help information"
    printf '%s\n' "             --different or -d"
    printf '%s\n' "                 - find URLs that differ"
    printf '%s\n' "             --common or -c"
    printf '%s\n' "                 - find URLs that are common"
    printf '%s\n' "             --domains"
    printf '%s\n' "                 - compare and print only the domains (plus subdomains) of the URLs for: the group 1 and the group 2 - for the '-c' or the '-d' flag"
    printf '%s\n' "             --domains-full"
    printf '%s\n' "                 - compare only the domains (plus subdomains) of the URLs but print the full URLs for: the group 1 and the group 2 - for the '-c' or the '-d' flag"
    printf '%s\n' "             --preserve-order or -p"
    printf '%s\n' "                 - preserve the order and the occurences in which the links appear in group 1 and in group 2"
    printf '%s\n' "                 - Warning: when using this flag - process substitution is used by this script - which does not work with the \"dash\" shell (throws an error). For this flag, you can use other \"dash\" syntax compatible shells, like: bash, zsh, ksh"
    printf '%s\n' "             --skip-non-text"
    printf '%s\n' "                 - skip non-text files from search (does not look into: .docx, .xlsx, .pptx, .ppsx, .odt, .ods, .odp and .pdf files)"
    printf '%s\n' "             --find-parameters <find_parameters>"
    printf '%s\n' "                 - all the parameters given after this flag, are considered 'find' parameters"
    printf '%s\n' "                 - <find_parameters> can be: any parameters that can be passed to the 'find' utility (which is used internally by this script) - such as: name/path filters"
    printf '%s\n' "             -h"
    printf '%s\n' "                 - also look in hidden files"
    printf '%s\n' "     "
    printf '%s\n' "     Output:"
    printf '%s\n' "         - '<' - denote URLs from the group 1: '/path/to/file1'"
    printf '%s\n' "         - '>' - denote URLs from the group 2: '/path/to/file2' ... '/path/to/fileN'"
    printf '%s\n' "     "
    printf '%s\n' "     Other commands that might be useful:"
    printf '%s\n' "         "
    printf '%s\n' "         - filter results - print lines containing string (highlight):"
    printf '%s\n' "             ...|grep \"string\""
    printf '%s\n' "         "
    printf '%s\n' "         - filter results - print lines not containing string:"
    printf '%s\n' "             ...|grep -v \"string\""
    printf '%s\n' "         "
    printf '%s\n' "         - filter results - print lines containing: string1 or string2 or ... stringN:"
    printf '%s\n' "             ...|awk '/string1|string2|...|stringN/'"
    printf '%s\n' "         "
    printf '%s\n' "         - filter results - print lines not containing: string1 or string2 or ... stringN:"
    printf '%s\n' "             ...|awk '"'!'"/string1|string2|...|stringN/'"
    printf '%s\n' "         "
    printf '%s\n' "         - filter results - print lines in '/file/path/2' that are in '/file/path/1':"
    printf '%s\n' "             grep -F -f '/file/path/1' '/file/path/2'"
    printf '%s\n' "         "
    printf '%s\n' "         - filter results - print lines in '/file/path/2' that are not in '/file/path/1':"
    printf '%s\n' "             grep -F -vf '/file/path/1' '/file/path/2'"
    printf '%s\n' "         "
    printf '%s\n' "         - filter results - print columns <1> and <2> from output:"
    printf '%s\n' "             awk '{print \$1, \$2}'"
    printf '%s\n' ""
}

###
CheckUtilities () {
    #Check if any of the necessary utilities is missing:
    
    if [ "$1" = '--warning' ]; then
        utility="$2"
        which $utility >/dev/null 2>/dev/null || { PrintErrorMessage "WARNING: the '$utility' utility is not installed! $3"; error="false"; }
    else
        error="false"
        for utility; do
            which $utility >/dev/null 2>/dev/null || { PrintErrorMessage "ERROR: the '$utility' utility is not installed!"; error="true"; }
        done
        if [ "$error" = "true" ]; then
            CleanUp && exit 1
        fi
    fi  
}

PrintErrorMessage () {
    printf '\n%s\n' "$1">&2
}

GenerateSequence () {
    sequence_start=$(($1))
    sequence_end=$(($2))
    if [ "$sequence_start" -le "$sequence_end" ]; then
        seq $sequence_start $sequence_end
    fi
}

GetMimeType () {
    eval current_file_path=\"\$$1\"
    
    #Get file mime encoding:
    if [ ! "${current_file_path#"/dev/"*}" = "${current_file_path}" ]; then
        result="ascii"
    else        
        if [ -d "$current_file_path" ]; then
            result="directory"
        else
            current_file_mime_type="$(file -bL --mime-encoding "$current_file_path" 2>/dev/null)"
            case "$current_file_mime_type" in
                *"binary"* )
                    result="binary"
                ;;
                *"ascii"* )
                    result="ascii"
                ;;
                *"utf"* )
                    result="utf"
                ;;
                *"inode/symlink"* )
                    result="directory"
                ;;
                * )
                    result="undetermined"
                ;;
            esac
        fi
    fi
    eval $2=\"\$result\"
}

ExtractFirstAndLastPathComponent () {
    eval current_path="\"\$$1\""
    
    first_path_component=""
    last_path_component=""
    
    if [ -n "$current_path" ]; then
        #Remove trailing '/' characters:
        while [ ! "${current_path%"/"}" = "$current_path" ]; do
            current_path="${current_path%"/"}"
        done
        
        if [ -z "$current_path" ]; then
            eval current_path=\"\$$1\"
        fi
        
        last_path_component="${current_path##*"/"}"
        first_path_component="${current_path%"$last_path_component"}"
    fi
    
    eval $2="\"\$first_path_component\""
    eval $3="\"\$last_path_component\""
}

GetCurrentShell () {
    if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then current_shell_name="bash";
    elif [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ]; then current_shell_name="zsh";
    elif [ -n "$KSH_VERSION" ]; then current_shell_name="ksh";
    elif [ "$PS1" = '$ ' ]; then current_shell_name="dash";
    else current_shell_name="dash"; #default shell
    fi
    current_shell_full_path="$(which "$current_shell_name")"
    
    eval $1=\"\$current_shell_name\"
    eval $2=\"\$current_shell_full_path\"
}
###


# Print to "/dev/tty" = Print error messages to screen only
print_to_screen="/dev/tty"

#print_error_messages='&2'
print_error_messages="$print_to_screen"

initial_dir="$PWD" #Store initial directory value

initial_IFS="$IFS" #Store initial IFS value

GetOSType OS_TYPE

NL2=$(printf '%s' "\n\n") #Store New Line for use with sed
TAB=$(printf '%s' "\t")

insert_NL_before_URLs_command='sed -E '"'"'s/([a-zA-Z]*\:\/\/)/'"\\${NL2}"'\1/g'"'"
strip_NON_URL_text_command='sed -E '"'"'s/((.*([^a-zA-Z+])|([a-zA-Z])))(([a-zA-Z])*\:\/\/)([^ ^'"${TAB}"'^>^<]*).*/\4\5\7/g'"'"
get_domains_command='sed '"'"'s/.*:\/\/\(.*\)/\1/g'"'"'|sed '"'"'s/\/.*//g'"'"
prepare_for_output_command='sed -E '"'"'s/ *([0-9]*)[\ *](<|>) *([0-9]*)[\ *](.*)/\2 \4 \1/g'"'"
remove_angle_brackets_command='sed -E '"'"'s/(<|>) (.*)/\2/g'"'"

delete_lines_not_containing_an_URL='sed -E '"'"'/.*\:\/\/.*/!d'"'"
extract_urls_command="$insert_NL_before_URLs_command|$strip_NON_URL_text_command|$delete_lines_not_containing_an_URL"

find_params=""

if [ "$OS_TYPE" = "Linux" ] || [ "$OS_TYPE" = "Other" ]; then
    find_negation='!'
elif [ "$OS_TYPE" = "BSD-based" ]; then
    find_negation='-not'
fi

#Process parameters:

different_flag="0"
common_flag="0"
domains_flag="0"
domains_full_flag="0"
preserve_order_flag="0"
dff_command1_flag="0"
dff_command2_flag="0"
dff_command3_flag="0"
dff_command4_flag="0"
dff_command_flag="0"
skip_non_text_files_flag="0"
find_parameters_flag="0"
hidden_files_flag="0"
help_flag="0"

flag_params_count=0
file_params_count=0
find_params_count=0

for param; do
    if [ "$find_parameters_flag" = "0" ]; then
        case "$param" in
            "--different" | "-d" | "--common" | "-c" | "--domains" | \
            "--domains-full" | "--preserve-order" | "-p" | "--dff_command1" | "--dff_command2" | \
            "--dff_command3" | "--dff_command4" | "--skip-non-text" | "--find-parameters" | "-h" | \
            "--help" )
                flag_params_count=$(($flag_params_count+1))
                eval flag_params_$flag_params_count=\"\$param\"
                case "$param" in
                    "--different" | "-d" )
                        different_flag="1"
                    ;;
                    "--common" | "-c" )
                        common_flag="1"
                    ;;
                    "--domains" )
                        domains_flag="1"
                    ;;
                    "--domains-full" )
                        domains_full_flag="1"
                    ;;
                    "--preserve-order" | "-p" )
                        preserve_order_flag="1"
                    ;;
                    "--dff_command1" )
                        dff_command1_flag="1"
                        dff_command_flag="1"
                    ;;
                    "--dff_command2" )
                        dff_command2_flag="1"
                        dff_command_flag="2"
                    ;;
                    "--dff_command3" )
                        dff_command3_flag="1"
                        dff_command_flag="3"
                    ;;
                    "--dff_command4" )
                        dff_command4_flag="1"
                        dff_command_flag="4"
                    ;;
                    "--skip-non-text" )
                        skip_non_text_files_flag="1"
                    ;;
                    "--find-parameters" )
                        find_parameters_flag="1"
                    ;;
                    "-h" )
                        hidden_files_flag="1"
                    ;;
                    "--help" )
                        help_flag="1"
                    ;;
                esac
            ;;
            * )
                file_params_count=$(($file_params_count+1))
                eval file_params_$file_params_count=\"\$param\"
            ;;
        esac
    elif [ "$find_parameters_flag" = "1" ]; then
        find_params_count=$(($find_params_count+1))
        eval find_params_$find_params_count=\"\$param\"
    fi
done
flag_params_0="$flag_params_count"
file_params_0="$file_params_count"
find_params_0="$find_params_count"

if [ "$help_flag" = "1" ] || ( [ "$file_params_0" = "0" ] && [ "$find_params_0" = "0" ] ); then
    DisplayHelp
    exit 0
fi

#Check if any of the necessary utilities is missing:

error="false"

CheckUtilities find file kill seq ps sort uniq sed grep cat unzip

if [ "$skip_non_text_files_flag" = "0" ]; then
    CheckUtilities unzip
    CheckUtilities --warning pdftohtml 'PDF files are going to be skipped!'
fi

if [ "$error" = "true" ]; then
    printf "\n"
    CleanUp; exit 1
fi

#Process parameters/flags and check for errors:

if [ ! "$find_params_0" = "0" ]; then
    find_params="$(for i in $(GenerateSequence 1 $find_params_0;); do eval printf \'\%s \' "\'\$find_params_$i\'"; done;)"
else
    find_params='-name "*"'
fi

if [ "$hidden_files_flag" = "1" ]; then
    hidden_files_string=""
elif [ "$hidden_files_flag" = "0" ]; then
    hidden_files_string="$find_negation"' -path ''"*/.*"'
fi

find_params="$hidden_files_string"" -a ""$find_params"

GetCurrentShell current_shell_name current_shell_full_path
cd "${0%/*}" 2>/dev/null; current_script_path="$(pwd -P)/${0##*/}"

error="false"

if [ "$domains_full_flag" = "1" ]; then
    if [ "$current_shell_name" = "dash" ]; then
        PrintErrorMessage "ERROR: The 'dash' shell is not supported for the '--domains-full' flag!"
        CleanUp && exit 1
    fi
fi

if [ "$different_flag" = "0" ] && [ "$common_flag" = "0" ]; then
    error="true"
    printf '\n%s\n' "ERROR: Expected either -c or -d flag!">"$print_error_messages"
elif [ "$different_flag" = "1" ] && [ "$common_flag" = "1" ]; then
    error="true"
    printf '\n%s\n' "ERROR: The '-c' flag cannot be used together with the '-d' flag!">"$print_error_messages"
fi

if [ "$preserve_order_flag" = "1" ] && [ "$common_flag" = "1" ]; then
    error="true"
    printf '\n%s\n' "ERROR: The '-p' flag cannot be used together with the '-c' flag!">"$print_error_messages"
fi

if [ "$preserve_order_flag" = "1" ] && [ "$current_shell_name" = "dash" ]; then
    error="true"
    printf '\n%s\n' "ERROR: When using the '-p' flag, the \"process substitution\" feature is needed, which is not available in the dash shell (it is available in shells like: bash, zsh, ksh)!">"$print_error_messages"
fi

eval find \'/dev/null\' "$find_params">/dev/null 2>&1||{
    error="true"
    printf '\n%s\n' "ERROR: Invalid parameters for the 'find' command!">"$print_error_messages"
}

if [ "$error" = "true" ]; then
    printf "\n"
    PrintErrorExtra
    CleanUp; exit 1;
fi

#Check if the file paths given as parameters do exist:
error="false"
for i in $(GenerateSequence 1 $file_params_0); do
    eval current_file=\"\$file_params_$i\"
    # If current <file> does not exist:
    if [ ! -e "$current_file" ]; then # If current file does not exist:
        printf '\n%s\n' "ERROR: File '$current_file' does not exist or is not accessible!">"$print_error_messages"
        error="true"
    elif [ ! -r "$current_file" ]; then # If current file is not readable:
        printf '\n%s\n' "ERROR: File <$i> = '$current_file' is not readable!">"$print_error_messages"
        error="true"
    fi
done

if [ "$error" = "true" ]; then
    printf "\n"
    PrintErrorExtra
    CleanUp; exit 1;
fi

#Expand file parameters to their full paths and re-store them:
for i in $(GenerateSequence 1 $file_params_0); do
    eval current_file=\"\$file_params_$i\"
    ExtractFirstAndLastPathComponent current_file fpc_current_file lpc_current_file
    cd "$initial_dir"
    cd "$fpc_current_file"
    current_file="$PWD/$lpc_current_file"
    eval file_params_$i=\"\$current_file\"
    cd "$initial_dir"
done

#Proceed to finding and comparing URLs:

IFS='
'

#Trap "INTERRUPT" (CTRL-C) and "TERMINAL STOP" (CTRL-Z) signals:
trap 'trap1' INT
trap 'trap1' TSTP

if [ "$domains_full_flag" = "0" ] || [ ! "$dff_command_flag" = "0" ]; then
    
    StoreURLsWithLineNumbers

fi

IFS=' 
'

if [ "$domains_full_flag" = "0" ]; then
    if [ "$preserve_order_flag" = "0" ]; then
        {
            for i in $(GenerateSequence 1 $lines11_0); do
                printf "\033]0;%s\007" "Processing group [1] - URL: $i...">"$print_to_screen"
                eval printf \"\%s\\n\" \"\< \$lines11_$i \$lines12_$i\"
            done|sort -k 3|uniq -c -f 2
            for i in $(GenerateSequence 1 $lines21_0); do
                printf "\033]0;%s\007" "Processing group [2] - URL: $i...">"$print_to_screen"
                eval printf \"\%s\\n\" \"\> \$lines21_$i \$lines22_$i\"
            done|sort -k 3|uniq -c -f 2
        }|sort -k 4|{
            if [ "$different_flag" = "1" ]; then
                uniq -u -f 3|sort -k 3|eval "$prepare_for_output_command"
            elif [ "$common_flag" = "1" ]; then
                uniq -d -f 3|sort -k 3|eval "$prepare_for_output_command"|eval "$remove_angle_brackets_command"
            fi
        }
    elif [ "$preserve_order_flag" = "1" ]; then
        
        if [ "$different_flag" = "1" ]; then
            {
                URL_count=0
                current_line=""
                for line in $(eval diff \
                        \<\(\
                            count1=0\;\
                            for i in \$\(GenerateSequence 1 $lines11_0\)\; do\
                                count1=\$\(\(\$count1 + 1\)\)\;\
                                eval URL=\\\"\\\$lines12_\$i\\\"\;\
                                printf \"\%s\\n\" \"File group: 1 URL: \$count1\"\;\
                                printf \"\%s\\n\" \"\$URL\"\;\
                            done\;\
                            printf \"\%s\\n\" \"\#\#\# Separator 1\"\;\
                        \) \
                        \<\(\
                            count2=0\;\
                            for i in \$\(GenerateSequence 1 $lines21_0\)\; do\
                                count2=\$\(\(\$count2 + 1\)\)\;\
                                eval URL=\\\"\\\$lines22_\$i\\\"\;\
                                printf \"\%s\\n\" \"File group: 2 URL: \$count2\"\;\
                                printf \"\%s\\n\" \"\$URL\"\;\
                            done\;\
                            printf \"\%s\\n\" \"\#\#\# Separator 2\"\;\
                        \) \
                    ); do
                    URL_count=$(($URL_count + 1))
                    previous_line="$current_line"
                    current_line="$line"
                    #if ( current line starts with "<" and previous line starts with "<" ) OR ( current line starts with ">" and previous line starts with ">" ):
                    if ( [ ! "${current_line#"<"}" = "${current_line}" ] && [ ! "${previous_line#"<"}" = "${previous_line}" ] ) || ( [ ! "${current_line#">"}" = "${current_line}" ] && [ ! "${previous_line#">"}" = "${previous_line}" ] ); then
                        printf '%s\n' "$previous_line"
                    fi
                done
            }
        
        fi
    fi
elif [ "$domains_full_flag" = "1" ]; then
    
    # Command to find common domains:
    script_command1="$current_shell_full_path '$current_script_path' -c --domains $(for i in $(GenerateSequence 1 $file_params_0); do eval current_param=\\\'\$file_params_$i\\\'; printf '%s ' "$current_param"; done; printf "\n";)"
    
    # URLs that are only in first parameter file (file group 1):
    script_command2="$current_shell_full_path '$current_script_path' -d '$file_params_1' \"/dev/null\""
    
    # Command to find common domains:
    script_command3="$current_shell_full_path '$current_script_path' -c --domains $(for i in $(GenerateSequence 1 $file_params_0); do eval current_param=\\\'\$file_params_$i\\\'; printf '%s ' "$current_param"; done; printf "\n";)"
    
    # URLs that are only in 2..N parameter files (file group 2):
    script_command4="$current_shell_full_path '$current_script_path' -d \"/dev/null\" $(for i in $(GenerateSequence 2 $file_params_0); do eval current_param=\\\'\$file_params_$i\\\'; printf '%s ' "$current_param"; done; printf "\n";)"
    
    #Store one <command substitution> at a a time (syncronously):
    script_command1_output="$(eval $script_command1 --dff_command1|sed 's/\([^ *]\) \(.*\)/\1/')"
    script_command2_output="$(eval $script_command2 --dff_command2)"
    script_command3_output="$(eval $script_command3 --dff_command3|sed 's/\([^ *]\) \(.*\)/\1/')"
    script_command4_output="$(eval $script_command4 --dff_command4)"
    
    if [ "$different_flag" = "1" ]; then
    # Find URLs (second escaped process substitution: \<\(...\)) that are not in the common domains list (first escaped process substitution: \<\(...\)):
        # URLs in the first file given as parameter (second escaped process substitution: \<\(...\)):
        eval grep \-F \-vf \<\( printf \'\%s\' \"\$script_command1_output\"\; \) \<\( printf \'\%s\' \"\$script_command2_output\"\; \)
        # URLs in the files 2..N - given as parameters (second escaped process substitution: \<\(...\)):
        eval grep \-F \-vf \<\( printf \'\%s\' \"\$script_command3_output\"\; \) \<\( printf \'\%s\' \"\$script_command4_output\"\; \)
    elif [ "$common_flag" = "1" ]; then
    # Find URLs (second escaped process substitution: \<\(...\)) that are in the common domains list (first escaped process substitution: \<\(...\)):
        # URLs in the first file given as parameter (second escaped process substitution: \<\(...\)):
        eval grep \-F \-f \<\( printf \'\%s\' \"\$script_command1_output\"\; \) \<\( printf \'\%s\' \"\$script_command2_output\"\; \)
        # URLs in the files 2..N - given as parameters (second escaped process substitution: \<\(...\)):
        eval grep \-F \-f \<\( printf \'\%s\' \"\$script_command3_output\"\; \) \<\( printf \'\%s\' \"\$script_command4_output\"\; \)
    fi
    # grep flags explained:
    #    -F = do not interpret pattern string (treat string literally)
    #    -v = select non-matching lines
fi

CleanUp
```

For the asked question - this should do it:

```
dash '/path/to/the/above/script.sh' -d '/path/to/file1/containing/URLs.txt' '/dev/null'
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming a well-formed `HTML` document with only 1 `href` link per line, here's one `awk` approach without needing `backreferences` to `regex`:`capturing groups`

> ```
> {m,g}awk 'NF*=2<NF' OFS= FS='^.*<[Aa] [^>]*[Hh][Rr][Ee][Ff]=\"|\".*$'
> ```

```
http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b03/simple-symmetry
http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b04/faces-and-a-vase
http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b05/blind-contour-drawing
http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b06/seeing-values
```

Answer (score 0):

I see nobody addressed the comment that windows console commands did not "work"

> I tried writing a batch file, and it told me FINDSTR is not an internal or external command

but if we **take the OP input at face value** (otherwise would need adjusting) then we could use `Findstr` (has regex) but `Find` is simpler

`type html.txt|find /i "http">temp.txt&for /f "tokens=2 delims==>" %f in (temp.txt) do @echo %f`

(for a Windows batchfile those %f will need to be double %%f)

will produce this result which can be redirected or be put in a second line stripped of the surrounding quotes, but unclear if may be needed for a downstream step where double quotes may be required as a Windows preference.

"http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b03/simple-symmetry"
"http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b04/faces-and-a-vase"
"http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b05/blind-contour-drawing"
"http://www.drawspace.com/lessons/b06/seeing-values"