# Spider a website and retrieve all links that contain a keyword

Tags: bash, copy, wget

How do I make a Bash script that will copy all links (non-download website). The function is only to get all the links and then save it in a txt file.

I've tried this code:

```
wget --spider --force-html -r -l1 http://somesite.com | grep 'Saving to:'
```

Example: there are download links within a website (for example, dlink.com), so I just want to copy all words that contain dlink.com and save it into a txt file.

I've searched around using Google, and I found none of it useful.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264626/how-to-strip-out-all-of-the-links-of-an-html-file-in-bash-or-grep-or-batch-and-s And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash

Comment: i think the two links are not related on my post , but thank you for the reply

Comment: You can use phantomjs too for this https://gist.github.com/antivanov/3848638

Answer (score 2):

Using a proper parser in [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -w

use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTML::LinkExtor;
use URI::URL;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my ($url, $f, $p, $res);

if(@ARGV) { 
    $url = $ARGV[0]; }
else {
    print "Enter an URL : ";
    $url = <>;
    chomp($url);
}

my @array = ();
sub callback {
   my($tag, %attr) = @_;
   return if $tag ne 'a';  # we only look closer at <a href ...>
   push(@array, values %attr) if $attr{href} =~ /dlink\.com/i;
}

# Make the parser.  Unfortunately, we don’t know the base yet
# (it might be diffent from $url)
$p = HTML::LinkExtor->new(\&callback);

# Request document and parse it as it arrives
$res = $ua->request(HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url),
                    sub {$p->parse($_[0])});

# Expand all URLs to absolute ones
my $base = $res->base;
@array = map { $_ = url($_, $base)->abs; } @array;

# Print them out
print join("\n", @array), "\n";
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply , that perl code works perfectly in a single link , is there any way to make it recursive ,crawl all pages ?

Comment: For some $ or €, I could do it, yes =)

Comment: drop me an email dude ,if it's reasonable i might do some