# How can I grab download links from a website

Tags: download, wget

Is there any way of getting download links from a website and put those like in a text file? 
To download hose files later in with wget ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the source of the website. You can use `wget link-of-the-webiste-you-want-to-grab-links-from` for that. Than you can sed the links like this: `sed -n 's/.*href="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' file`

The [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264626/how-to-strip-out-all-of-the-links-of-an-html-file-in-bash-or-grep-or-batch-and-s) for details.

Answer (score 0):

With this you can download **jpg** file, instead of **jpg** you can give **any file format** which should be present in source_file. Your downloading links list will be in **link.txt**

```
grep -Po 'href=\"\/.+\.jpg' source_file | sed -n 's/href="\([^"]*\)/\1/p' >link.txt; wget -i link.txt
```