# How to get text from anchor tag in an HTML response using bash script

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, html-parsing

My HTML content is as follows:

```
<html>
<head><title>Index </title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<h1>Index of /Test/</h1><hr><pre><a href="../">../</a>
<a href="1.0/">1.0/</a>                                              17-Mar-2018 17:36                   -
<a href="1.1/">1.1/</a>                                              19-Jun-2018 19:22                   -
<a href="1.2/">1.2/</a>                                              22-Sep-2018 00:18                   -
<a href="documents/">documents/</a>                                             25-Apr-2018 23:40                   -
<a href="samples">samples</a>                                            03-Sep-2018 16:00              403699
</pre><hr></body>
</html>
```

I get the above HTML output by making a request to the server.

From the HTML output, I want to my final output to be as follows:

```
1.0
1.1
1.2
documents
samples
```

How can I get that the above output using bash script?

Comment: This is closely related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264626/

Comment: Yeah that's right. But I want to get anchor tag text value not href values even though both are same in my case.

Comment: Post valid HTML.

Comment: @karan essentially copy pasted my answer there with a minor update to retrieve your requested values. But be aware that your output is missing the first anchor and also the `href` attribute-value and anchor value are always the same.

Comment: @tripleee why is this considered "too broad"?

Comment: @kvantour https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/90230?m=43837669#43837669

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex to parse HTML or XML files is essentially [not done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348). Tools such as `sed` and `awk` are extremely powerful for handling text files, but when it boils down to parsing complex-structured data — such as XML, HTML, JSON, ... —  they are nothing more than a sledgehammer. Yes, you can get the job done, but sometimes at a tremendous cost.  For handling such delicate files, you need a bit more finesse by using a more targetted set of tools.

In case of parsing XML or HTML, one can easily use [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php).

In case of an XHTML file, you can use :

```
xmlstarlet sel --html  -N "x=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" \
               -t -m '//x:a' -v . -n
```

where `-N` gives the XHTML namespace if any, this is recognized by

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

However, As HTML pages are often not well-formed XML, it might be handy to clean it up a bit using [`tidy`](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/). In the example case above this gives then :

```
$ tidy -q -numeric -asxhtml --show-warnings no <file.html> \
  | xmlstarlet sel --html -N "x=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" \
                   -t -m '//x:a' -v . -n
../
1.0/
1.1/
1.2/
documents/
samples
```

Comment: I love downvoting without any comment.

Comment: Same... it's usually accompanied by a comment on the question by a certain someone, though.

Comment: @BenjaminW. and another downvote

Answer (score 0):

Using the HTML-XML-utils from https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils:

```
$ hxnormalize -x infile.html | hxselect -c -s '\n' a
../
1.0/
1.1/
1.2/
documents/
samples
```

The `hxnormalize` step is required because of the rogue `<hr>` tag (`hxselect` requires well-formed input); the `-x` option stands for "use XML conventions".

The `hxselect a` step extracts all anchor elements; the `-c` option prints content only, and `-s '\n'` separates the results with a newline.

If you really don't want the trailing `/`, you can pipe to `tr -d '/'`.

Comment: Nice solution. I was not aware of `hxnormalize` and the entire toolkit

Comment: @kvantour The html-xml-utils are neat, but I don't think anybody still maintains them. Edit: oh, never mind, changelog has changes as recent as a few months ago.